# Embedded Chat [Legacy] migration to Messaging In App Web

Tags: lightning-web-components, migration, chat, embedded, messaging

Does any one perform full migration to MIAW from Legacy embedded chat ?

If so, how do we manage 4 LWC components [Pre-Chat, Chat Header, Chat Message and Minimised]?

Given MIAW only had one component that support LWC currently as per their release plan or Road map it is ready for Summer 24, that too 1 more component and not all other three components